# Unable to amplify the docker image using existing VPC and subnets

Tags: reactjs, docker, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbaWO.jpg)I am able to amplify the docker image using cloudformation template but by using so it usage default vpc and subnets but I want to specify the VPC and subnets of my own.

Tried : I tried multiple attempt by updating stack of cloudformation template.

Expecting: I am trying to use existing VPC and pvt. subnets for deploying docker containers to AWS amplify.